# defining preprocessor definitions on a single file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm in the process of migrating a project to C++17.  There are a couple instances of old code with deprecation warning not within my control. An example of one of these warning is, `_SILENCE_CXX17_SHARED_PTR_UNIQUE_DEPRECATION_WARNING`. In visual studio, I've been adding these to `properties->Preprocessor Def`.  So far this is working fine.

To prevent the possibilities of me or someone else creating new deprecated code in the future somewhere else in the project, **is there a way to minimize the scope of the preprocess definition down to a single file instead of an entire project?**

Comment: define it in the file rather than the project settings? Or just don't define it at all and fix the deprecated code

Comment: @AlanBirtles, Ideally the smaller the better.  RSahu's solution works on a single project. Is it possible to get all the way down to a single cpp/h file?

Comment: @J'e You use the same `properties->Preprocessor Def` but you open the settings pages by right-clicking the individual `.cpp` file, not the entire project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to minimize the scope of the preprocess definition down to a single file?

Yes, it is possible to have different preprocessor macros for a single file in Visual Studio.

In the Solution Explorer, RMB -> Properties on a specific file to change its properties.